# Using RequireJS in a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, requirejs, conflict

I created a bookmarklet using require js, it is just fine on all sites except those who already use requirejs.
I searched in the documentation, I don't find any "no conflict mode" like jquery or something to manage multiple versions. Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not checking if require is already present on the page and do not load your own one in this case?

Comment: Have you looked at doing something like this: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion

Answer (score 0):

before including your script, check if "require" object is defined. only include the script if the object is undefined

```
if(typeof require != 'undefined') {
   //include script
}
```